# Can I list an educational paper in my publications?

Tags: cv, faculty-application

I have published a paper in *Journal of Chemical Education* by my supervisor. This is about a teaching approach for an undergraduate course. The paper was peer-reviewed and we spent more time on it than a research paper.

In my CV (I am applying for a faculty position), the list of publications is normally peer-reviewed research articles. Can I add this paper to the same list or it is better to create a separate section in my CV?

My worry is that this may undermine the entire list that some of other papers are not based on cutting-edge research.

Comment: Was the article a research article?

Comment: Always err on the side of clarity. I vote to create a separate section in your CV.

Comment: Does your paper provide new insights or collect information in a way that hasn't been done before? If so, what's the issue? Is it simply that it's a different field from your usual?

Comment: What makes you think that your peer-reviewed journal paper doesn't describe cutting-edge research?

Comment: Forty years ago when I was working towards tenure in an electrical engineering department, the dean of engineering told me that in his mind, journal articles counted as 10 points, conference papers as 3 points and publications in the _IEEE Transactions on Education_ as -3 points when he was deciding which assistant professors would be recommended for promotion and tenure!  Things have changed somewhat since then but there is still a bias against junior faculty "wasting"their time on teaching (and writing it up for publication) versus doing productive research.

Answer (score 20):

It is very simple: everything that is published is a publication. However, some authors choose to only list peer-reviewed publications. In both cases your educational paper qualifies.

Of course you are free to list certain types of publications in separate sections on your CV if you think it is better. How that is viewed depends on the person reading the CV. For what it's worth: in my opinion any list of publications has papers that are better than others even if it is all original research. There is no reason to list it separately.

Answer (score 3):

An easy resolution is, you can organize your publications in two categories. Enlist the regular "cutting-edge" research papers first, and later on, add a separate heading: *Other Publications*, in which you can refer to these variety as *Undergraduate Research Publication(s)*. The latter category will only be a bonus as far as the research profile is concerned, since it indicates that you were into mini-research even before getting to grad school. That is definitely a plus-point, or even at worst, mentioning this doesn't seem to have any negative point for sure.

Comment: I think you misread the question. It wasn't a paper about research that the OP was involved in as an undergraduate, it's a paper about undergraduate education.

Comment: @ff524 - Yes, in retrospection. But I believe the answer stands, no?